# Bounty notice overlaps with add comment link

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

As can be seen [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173265) at the time of posting, the add comment link overlaps with the bounty notice a little bit.

Windows 8.1

Chrome 35, Firefox 30 and IE11 all have the issue, so it doesn't seem to be a browser issue either.

[image: add comment]

Comment: Can Repro, though it's much less severe (just the tops of the d's/t) on an iPad.

Comment: Also reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233821/the-add-comment-link-and-comment-box-overlaps-bounty-box). I'll see about fixing this week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, which should be in the next 8 hours.